# I want to convert this SQL query to linq using C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq

I want to convert this SQL query to Linq in C#:

```
select
    count(*),
    FORMAT (CreatedDate, 'MM') as months,
    FORMAT (CreatedDate, 'yyyy') as year
from
    ProviderPosts
group by
    FORMAT (CreatedDate, 'MM'),
    FORMAT (CreatedDate, 'yyyy')
```

Comment: You can't convert SQL to Linq without first having an EF DbContext set-up. You haven't posted any details of how you've set-up Entity Framework, so we cannot help you.

Comment: Also, `FORMAT` in SQL Server is really slow: `CONVERT` is much faster (albeit far less flexible), but in any event what you're doing is one of the slowest ways to group-by-months, instead just use `YEAR( CreatedDate )` and `MONTH( CreatedDate )` (as they return `int` values) without using `FORMAT` nor `CONVERT` (nor `CAST`) (which are inappropriate because you're formatting text when you should only be concerned with the numeric values).

Comment: I changed it to month() and year() thank u ,, but I want to convert it to linQ, can you help me?

Comment: I just explained why we can't help you: because you haven't posted details of your `DbContext`.

Comment: @Dai really? The only way to turn LINQ into SQL is with EF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do not convert to anything. Use `.Year` and `.Month`

```cs
var query =
  from pp in ProviderPosts
  group pp by new { pp.CreatedDate.Year, pp.CreatedDate.Month } into g
  select new 
  {
      Count = g.Count(),
      g.Key.Month,
      g.Key.Year,
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code is an almost exact translation of your query, however depending on the LINQ provider it may not be able to translate it to SQL.

```cs
from pp in ProviderPosts
group pp by new DateTime(pp.CreatedDate.Year, pp.CreatedDate.Month, 1) into g
select new {
    Count = g.Count(),
    months = g.Key.ToString("MM"),
    year = g.Key.ToString("yyyy"),
}
```

> In SQL, it is more efficient to group by `EOMONTH` or `DATEFROMPARTS` rather than `FORMAT`

Comment: I think using var ````p```` instead of ````pp```` in ````DateTime```` constructor is a typo.

Comment: What happens if `p.CreatedDate` is nullable, though?

Comment: @Dai If it was LINQ to Objects then yes you'd have a problem, but EF and Linq2SQL just translate it direct, and SQL functions return null on null input. Null is a valid value to group by